# Python and Selenium - Pick value from dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to pick value in the dropwdown list as shown in picture - Dresses

Dropdown IMAGE with open HTML
[image: Dropdown IMAGE with open HTML]

By this line i'm able to click and expand the dropdown

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div'))).click()
myElem.click()
```

After i expand the dropdown list i tried to pick xPath/CSS selector for Dresses but nothing works

How i copy the Selector
[image: How i copy the Selector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and click on first dropdown div tag to expand and the click on the `dropdown` item.Hope this will work.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.dropdown__selector"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown__menu')]//li[@class='dropdown__menu_item']//a[@data-et-on-tab='women' and text()='Dresses']"))).click()
```

**Update**

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.dropdown__selector"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'dropdown__selector')]/following::div[1]//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown__menu')]//li[@class='dropdown__menu_item']//a[@data-et-on-tab='women' and text()='Dresses']"))).click()
```

Comment: First one works but the second don't. It expand the drop down list but not not picking the item

Comment: @Rookieprogrammer : Steps to reach that level?

Comment: After you got account navigate to https://poshmark.com/create-listing?

Comment: Sorry I can't login.However can you try the updated xpath.

Comment: still wont pick the value in dropdown list

Comment: if you are interested i can share session with you so we can go over it and use debugger ?